# Loading Song from file with Uri - XNA 4.0

Tags: uri, xna-4.0

I am attempting to load a song from Uri for use in my game. Code as below:

```
Uri uriStreaming = new Uri("file://E:/MySong.mp3");

Song song = Song.FromUri("Song Name", uriStreaming);

MediaPlayer.IsMuted = false;

MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.5f;

MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

When I get in game no audio is playing at all, though I have no errors at all. I've also tried it with a **http:/ link** for an mp3 and it works fine, so I'm not quite sure of the issue.

Any ideas for a fix?

Edit: After further investigation of this problem, I've found out that it's the ID3 tags causing the issue, **specifically if it is ID3v2.4** and if I use a tool to remove them, it plays fine. However, I can't expect my user to do this with all of their audio, so is there a workaround for this?

Comment: for me it throws and exception when I try to do a similar thing